# Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'unknown' Observable<Course[]> in Rxjs 6

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6

As I'm trying to use **filter** like this.

```
    beginnerCourses$: Observable<Course[]>;
    advancedCourses$: Observable<Course[]>;

    ngOnInit() {

      const http$ = createHttpObservables('/api/courses');

    const courses$ = http$.pipe(
      map(res => Object.values(res["payload"]))
    )

      this.beginnerCourses$ = http$
      .pipe(
          map(courses => courses
              .filter(course => course.category == 'BEGINNER')) //here problem is showing
      );
      
      this.advancedCourses$ = http$
      .pipe(
        map(courses => courses
          .filter(course => course.category == 'ADVANCED')) //here problem is showing
      );

      courses$.subscribe(courses => {
        this.beginnerCourses$ = courses.filter(course => course.category == 'BEGINNER'); //its working here
        this.advancedCourses$ = courses.filter(course => course.category == 'ADVANCED'); //its working here
      }, noop,
      () => console.log('completed'));
    }
```

The problem is  `Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'unknown'` for 
`map(courses => courses.filter(course => course.category == 'BEGINNER')))` and 
`map(courses => courses.filter(course => course.category == 'ADVANCED')))`

As i'm enrolled in a course it shows this way and in his tutorial its working. But i don't know what i'm missing here.

**Update 1:**
Used it.

```
.pipe(
  map((courses: any[]) => courses.filter(
    course => course.category == 'BEGINNER')
  )
);
```

But in Edge Console it shows.

```
ERROR TypeError: courses.filter is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

I was doing this tutorial and ran across the same problem.

I found that you need to specify the type for the courses$ observable:

> const courses$: **Observable<Course[]>** = http$.pipe(
> map(res => Object.values(res["payload"]))
> )

But you also need to specify the **courses$** observable and not the http$
observable when you assign it to beginnerCourses$ as below:

> ```
>  this.beginnerCourses$ = courses$
>  .pipe(
>      map(courses => courses
>          .filter(course => course.category == 'BEGINNER')) 
>  );
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is a typescript error, it means that map doesn't know the type of observable it's transforming.

You can give typescript the typing informaiton a few different ways.

Try:

```
.pipe(
  map((courses: any[]) => courses.filter(
    course => course.category == 'BEGINNER')
  )
);
```

Comment: ERROR TypeError: courses.filter is not a function in the Edge console mode.

Comment: looks like http$ doesn't emit what you think it does. I can't fix that for you though.

Answer (score 0):

add **Observable<Course[]>** to courses$

```
const courses$: Observable<Course[]> = http$.pipe(
  map(res => Object.values(res["payload"]))
)
```